Explanation for $A^n$
I am trying to solve this problem at the end of this video from 3b1b:

$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1  \\
1 &1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$
Start computing its first few powers by hand: $A^2$, $A^3$, etc. What pattern do you see? Can you explain why this pattern shows up? This might make you curious to know if there's an efficient way to compute arbitrary powers of this matrix, $A^n$ for any number $n$.
Given that two eigenvectors of this matrix are
$$ \vec{\mathbf{v}}_1=\begin{bmatrix}
2  \\
1+\sqrt5
\end{bmatrix}\qquad  \vec{\mathbf{v}}_2=\begin{bmatrix}
2  \\
1-\sqrt5
\end{bmatrix},$$
see if you can figure out a way to compute $A^n$ by first changing to an eigenbasis, compute the new representation of $A^n$ in that basis, then converting back to our standard basis. What does the formula tell you?

By calculating $A^2$,$A^3$,$A^4$,$A^5$ and $A^6$, I came up with this:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1  \\
1 &1 
\end{bmatrix} , A{^2}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1  \\
1 &2 
\end{bmatrix},A{^n}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11,n-1}+a_{11,n-2} &a_{12,n-1}+a_{12,n-2}  \\
a_{21,n-1}+a_{21,n-2} &a_{22,n-1}+a_{22,n-2} 
\end{bmatrix}, n\ge 3$$
where $a_{ij,n}$ is the number in the postion $ij$ of $A^n$
I have no idea of why this pattern shows up; then, after doing what the second part says:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &2  \\
1+\sqrt{5} &1-\sqrt{5} 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\times \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11,n-1}+a_{11,n-2} &a_{12,n-1}+a_{12,n-2}  \\
a_{21,n-1}+a_{21,n-2} &a_{22,n-1}+a_{22,n-2} 
\end{bmatrix}\times \begin{bmatrix}
2 &2  \\
1+\sqrt{5} &1-\sqrt{5} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
I simply get a monstruosity in terms of the components of $A^n$:
Please help
(I realized I wrote the wrong matrix, the correct matrix is much more larger and I don´t think it´s worth writing it down)
Update:
After computing $A^n$ by first changing to an eigenbasis and then calculating the new representation of $A^n$ in that basis, I reached to this point:
$$P^{-1}(AP)^n=(AP)^{n-1}$$
where $P$ is the eigenbasis formed by $v_1$ and $v_2$ (I don´t know if this is right so please correct me if it isn´t). The difference between this question and the one proposed in the comment section is that you should arrive to something like $A^n=P^{-1}D^nP$ from the equation above (or any other finding that I haven´t find) and not suppose that it would be good if $A^n=P^{-1}D^nP$, which is the approach taken by the answer of said question (Or at least that´s what I think, please correct me if I´m wrong).

@peterwhy I just edited the question answering your comment

If you reached $P^{-1}(AP)^n = (AP)^{n-1}$, then a particular case $n=1$ would mean $P^{-1}AP = I$ or $AP=P$ or even $A=I$. This does not match $AP=PD$ from the eigenvalues (all $\ne 1$) and eigenvectors.

Look up how the matrix of a linear operator changes when you change the basis. It's not simply multiplication by $P$.

The problem says:

compute $A^n$ by first changing to an eigenbasis

(emphasis mine). Try first changing the matrix $A$ (!) to the eigenbasis and then looking if it makes raising it to a power easier.
Also, what is the sequence that is formed by, say, top-right elements of $A^n$? Your pattern guess is correct, I believe, but the sequence has a name.

Ohhh it´s the fibonacci numbers (at least in the top right)! Also thanks for making me realize the "by first changing to an eigenbasis" part.

Hint: Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. $Q = [\begin{matrix} v_1 &\cdots &v_n\end{matrix}]$ where $v_1,...,v_n$ are the eigenvectors of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1,..,\lambda_n$. Suppose $v_1,...,v_n$ are linear independent, prove that
$$A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$$
where $\Lambda$ is a matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues
